# Windows Firewall dropping Packets

Tags: sql-server, windows-firewall

I'm running into some odd behavior trying to configure a highly available remote desktop connection broker scenario. I'm using Windows 2016 and the SQL Server 2016 client connectivity tools (SQL Server Native Client 11.0).

During the configuration, it requires a SQL Server connection string, which I've triple checked as correct. When it configured, it does not find the SQL Server. I've isolated the problem to the Windows Firewall and here is what I've discovered:

Firewall service disabled: Works.
Firewall service enabled, but firewall turned off: Does not work.
Firewall service enabled, firewall turned on: Does not work.
Firewall service enabled, firewall turned on, exceptions allowing all traffic: Does not work.

This also seems to only affect using a named SQL Instance. If I use the default instance, there are no issues. With logging enabled on the firewall, I can see the following:

> 2017-09-06 13:28:01 DROP UDP 10.59.128.18 10.59.28.217 49577 1434 0 - - - - - - - SEND

If I run a capture on the Microsoft Network Monitor while trying this, it does not show ANY traffic on port 1434 with the firewall on and exceptions configured. If I disable the firewall service, the network monitor does show traffic on 1434.

One other test I did was reset the firewall to defaults and verify there are no denials taking places. I noticed a ton of dropped packets in the log, as expected. When add the allow all rules, all of those dropped packets are then allowed EXCEPT for the ones going through 1434. Every article I find regarding this explains opening up ports in the Windows Firewall, which is already done.

I also tried the connection string using the currently assigned dynamic port of the SQL instance and it worked, but that is not a solution as the dynamic port will change.

Comment: For your firewall exceptions, what exceptions did you put? Did you set it to allow all traffic to port 1434? Is the SQL Server Browsing Service enabled?

Comment: 1434 is the port for the SQL Server Browser service, which is required for resolving ports for named instances, so this traffic is expected (and it's also expected that things work for the default instance even if the Browser service can't be contacted). Is UDP traffic to port 1434 enabled?

Comment: I've tried it with all ports as well as just 1434. There is no SQL Server browser on the Windows server as it doesn't have SQL installed, just the connectivity tools. The issue appears to be in how the request is interacting with the firewall and the packet isn't even reaching the SQL server based on my network monitoring.

Comment: The machine hosting SQL Server needs to have this service running and the inbound ports open, not the machines connecting to it. If it's only the client machine blocking the packets, then check the rules for *outbound* connections.

Comment: It looks likes it's the client machine as the network monitor isn't showing any outbound traffic on 1434. The rules mentioned above are outbound connection rules.

Comment: Double check your rules -- traffic must be allowed from "local port: any" to "remote port: 1434". Also double-check under "advanced" that the rule applies to all scopes. If all else fails, try resetting/repairing the firewall configuration if your setup allows it ("Restore Default Policy"). It's blocking the outbound packet, that's for sure.

Comment: I've already done a reset on the firewall after significant troubleshooting. I get the same behavior no matter if local/remote is any/any, any/1434,1434,1434 or anything in between. But this behavior also only happens when the connection string contains the instance like server\instance.

Comment: Yes, because that's the only case where the SQL client must contact the browser to resolve the port for the remote instance. If you specify an explicit port, or contact the default instance, it doesn't do that, so the firewall blocking 1434 is no issue then.

Comment: There is something else going on. Everything indicates that the packets should be allowed. It also doesn't work if the firewall profiles are turned off (with the service enabled).

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what the matter could be, besides it being localized in the firewall. To verify you're not going insane, try the same from a clean VM, or another machine, or other nuclear options like `netsh winsock reset`. If all else fails, try Microsoft support. I've never dealt with them myself, but I do hear they occasionally help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by disabling the Named Pipes protocol on the SQL Native Client on the client machine.